# Connotation vs. Subtext

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

Can these two words ever be used interchangeably?

My intuition as a writer tells me that I can either say (for example)

> The word denotes (x), but its connotation is (y).

or

> The definition of the word is (x), but it has a (y) subtext.

Both sound completely acceptable. But is this technically correct?

Comment: Normally we'd say a text has a subtext and a word or phrase has a connotation.  The subtext is the story below the story.

Comment: While both are acceptable (connotation applies to signs and subtext to texts, but words are clearly easily seen as either), I'd question your use of /is/ in the example. Connotations appear in a context (the syntax of a work; signs related by adjacency) and in contrast to what is not said and this sign usurps (in paradigm, style, etc: "it's not what you said, it's what you didn't say"). I think the most you can say is "can have" or "typically have", maybe even "can be seen/used to have", particularly in your 2nd example, where a word is typically (but not always) a component of a larger text.

Comment: Could you add an example from actual usage of the second?  Subtext in my experience is a synonym of "backstory", i.e. it is an unstated narrative, which to me is quite a different thing than connotation.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these words deal with implied meaning, but the difference appears to be their scope. From the definitions in OED2, the simple difference appears to be that **connotation applies to the definition of a single word, while subtext is the underlying meaning in a broader text**.

### Connotation

> 1.1 The signifying in addition; inclusion of something in the meaning of a word besides what it primarily denotes; implication.
>   b.1.b That which is implied in a word in addition to its essential or primary meaning.

and in logic,

> b.2.b With J. S. Mill and later logicians: The attribute or aggregate of attributes connoted by a term.

### subtext

> 2.2 An underlying theme in a piece of writing (esp. in a novel or play).

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st. phrase, *"The word denotes (x), but its connotation is (y)."* is fine because despite it denotes the word has a connotation.

However, *"The definition of the word is (x), but it has a (y) subtext."* is rather strange - or poor - because word has no "subtext" but a meaning & even a connotation sometimes. So you should here **switch subtext for connotation**. Do it ! you have the word...

(Beside this, we understand in your context that "subtext" has to be taken for "connotation".)

So to answer you, **"subtext" wouldn't here be technically correct**.

Answer (score 0):

CONNOTATION and SUBTEXT can't be used interchangeably.Connotation and denotation are the subject matters of elementary logic:

- Denotation = Span/Scope(meaning)
- Connotation = depth/designation/go
  in the making(quality)
- Subtext = meaning underneath a text,
  speech or dialogue(motives)

When we mean 'MAN', it denotes 'all men', its connotation is 'animality & rationality' — man's identifying characteristics and "Subtext" is man's different emotions like 'love', 'anger', 'pity' or hate. However, we would explain SUBTEXT a bit in details.

Subtext as Wikipedia has it, is content of a creative work implicit in the work itself and realized by the reader or audience as the work progresses or the plot unfolds. Subtext is the content underneath the dialogue or the motive or impulse driving a character to act. I bid you 'farewell', but you can gather from my intonation, appearance or any gesture if I am hearty or heinous. It is SUBTEXT. Meta-message 
is the modernized name of subtext.

Hope this will help you to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

- **Connotation is *implication*** ("posting on SE connotes having time on your hands")
- **Subtext is *underlying meaning*** ("that post has as subtext *the Internet is doomed*").

Answer (score 0):

Subtext doesn't have to be known to the character (consciously or unconsciously) or possibly even to the author, although I think you will get some argument about the latter. In Kafka, for example, the subtext is clearly not generally (weasel word!) evident to the characters.

Comment: Can you make this a complete answer? What about connotation?